# black line left and right of text

Tags: html, css

I would like to put a black line to the left and right side of a heading, so it looks like:

-------------------- Beautiful text ---------------------------

content bla bla blab content bla bla blab content bla
content bla bla blab content bla bla blab content bla
content bla bla blab content bla bla blab content bla
content bla bla blab content bla bla blab content bla

Hoping you know what I mean.

What's the best way to do this? I can achieve this by giving the h1 a negative top-position and a white background while setting the content's div with a black border on top. So the heading (with a white background) overlays my black border.

But I'm sure there's a nicer way than working with negative positioning.

Comment: When asking *"What's **the best** way to do X?"* always provide context and explain the issues with your current solution.

Comment: See my answer below. http://jsfiddle.net/jYW4n/22/show/ The line is right in the vertical middle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://fiddle.jshell.net/MF4WP/4/
http://fiddle.jshell.net/MF4WP/4/show

```
<h1><span>My heading has a line through it.</span></h1>
```

The extra span is needed.
Works also with multi-line headings:
See example here:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/aZ4tr/6/show
http://fiddle.jshell.net/aZ4tr/6/

```
 h1 {
    color: gray;
    font-size: 0; /* fixes white-space issue SPAN */
    font-family:Helvetica;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 10px;
    position: relative;
}
h1:before {
  content: '';
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  background: gray;
  position:absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -1px;
}
h1 span {
    background: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 28px;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use pseudo element in absolute position and negative margin:
**Basic one line version:**

http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/FzjiD/

```
h1 {
  margin:0 1em;
  position:relative;/*here triggers overflow since no width is given */
  overflow:hidden;
  text-align:center;
}
h1:after , h1:before{
  content:'';
  margin-top:0.5em;
  height:0;
  border-top:groove 2px;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  margin-right:-100%;/* reduce size virtually to zero at 100% */
  margin-left:1%;/* set margin from end  text */
}
h1:before{
  margin-left:-101%;/* reduce size virtually to zero at 100% + give margin from begin text */
}
```

**For multilines lines :**

http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/uLynl/
you need to set `top` coordonates to keep in vertical middle;
and wrap text into inline-box to not overlay it . http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/qhEro/

Comment: Works great as well. See my fork: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GvHaF You can put it vertically centred by using top:50%; + margin-top: -[borderwidth]px

Comment: Only one problem what happens with mutlt-line headings it will break.

Comment: @JohanVandenRym answer updated , see the 2 forks of initial pen and undesrtand how this works

Comment: It should work also without adding <br> to the text like here: http://jsfiddle.net/37KQS/4/show

Comment: ? then obviuously you need to set a width or a max-width to span or at least some horizontal padding to h1 to reduce width avalaible for text being layed

Comment: That will be the case when the heading is in a columnar lay-out you can have the heading span multiple lines.

Comment: your fiddle shows the line all the way through when you resize window height, is that meant to be ? (i can provide a screen shot if you are curious)  http://i.stack.imgur.com/B9Nml.jpg

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/B9Nml.jpg resize your frame on height in fiddle :) http://jsfiddle.net/37KQS/4/  the cure is display:inline-block on span http://jsfiddle.net/37KQS/5/

Comment: What browser do you see this it works fine since the span centred in the middle has a white background that cover the horizontal line. Very weird.

Comment: use another color to show background of span to understand what i talk about , browsers uses different font-size, font family and line-height if not set :)

Comment: I see it now on Chrome.

Comment: inline-block does add white-space

Comment: yep :) , beside , i would have build it so http://jsfiddle.net/37KQS/6/ , to avoid line to diseaper behind  background  if h1 as any http://jsfiddle.net/37KQS/10/

Comment: Fixed white-space issue http://fiddle.jshell.net/MF4WP/3/show/

Comment: thx, for the z-index:-1;  thing , there's a fix to bring pseudo line back in view http://jsfiddle.net/37KQS/11/ opacity has this funny effect and way to fix it ;) works better in every browser , if span has layout http://jsfiddle.net/37KQS/13/

Comment: Your technique with my span: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/syJgt

Comment: heu , you do not to reset font-size if span is inline-block ?http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/gucto  else , one here wich is alive  http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/Djhkd i'll be off next hours :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but its surely a simple way to achieve this:

HTML Code:

```
<hr class="headingrule" /><span id="heading">text</span><hr class="headingrule" />
```

CSS code:

```
.headingrule {
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
}

#heading {
    float: left;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5u9zF/1/).